# onclick and to in a link tag, I need onclick to be executed first

Tags: reactjs

The link tag is from a list of items, it is like a "navigation guide". It turns out that I am needing the function that is in the link tag, the "onClick", to be executed first and then redirect to the "to" after it is executed. Because I am needing first onClick and then to, because onclick opens a collapse menu and then it must look for the item element.id on the page with the react scroll because if it does not execute onclick first the menu does not open and the guy is not going to find anything in the dom of the page

This is the function:

```
  @autobind
  getPreviewMenuChildren(element: any, parent: any) {
    let menuItem = undefined
    if (element["children"].length > 0) {
      menuItem = <div>
          <li>
              <Link onClick={() => this.getElementId(!!parent ? [element.id, parent.id] : [element.id])} to={element.id} spy={true} smooth={true}> {element.title}</Link></li>
        <ul>
          {element["children"].map((child: any) => { return this.getPreviewMenuChildren(this.state.items[child],element) })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    }
    else {
        menuItem = <li><Link onClick={() => this.getElementId(!!parent ? [element.id, parent.id] : [element.id])} to={element.id} spy={true} smooth={true}> {element.title}</Link></li>
    }
    return menuItem
  }
```

The tag is:

```
<Link onClick={() => this.getElementId(!!parent ? [element.id, parent.id] : [element.id])} to={element.id} spy={true} smooth={true}> {element.title}</Link></li>
```

It is important that first the onclick is executed on that label and then redirects to the to, because the onclick opens the collapse menu and the to goes and searches with the scroll for the position of the element.id

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition with the `onClick` event and `to` prop as they are both competing to fire at the same time. In this case, the React scroll behaviour will take precedence over the `onClick` event.

Instead of using the `to` prop, you could control the scroll behaviour programmatically in your `onClick`:

```
getPreviewMenuChildren(element: any, parent: any) {
  const handleLinkClick = () => {
    this.getElementId(!!parent ? [element.id, parent.id] : [element.id]);

    scroller.scrollTo(element.id, {
      duration: 800,
      delay: 0,
      smooth: 'easeInOutQuart'
    });
  };

  return (
    <Link onClick={handleLinkClick}>
      {element.title}
    </Link>
  );
}
```

This is a starting point and you will need to complete the rest of your code as required. Good luck!